# Как загрузить приложение на телефон?

Tags: android, eclipse

После написания приложения под андроид, как запустить его в телефоне?

Comment: читать FAQ по Android на 4pda.ru

Answer (score 2):

В Eclipse никаких специальных действих делать не нужно, если установлен ADT Plugin и открыт готовый проект. Нужно а) собрать его, б) поставить на выполнение. Тогда сама IDE загрузит его на телефон и запустит.

Или как вариант, можно установить приложение вручную

```
adb install приложение.apk
```

Перед установкой проверить, что устройство подключено

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала найти драйвер для гуглофона и на телефоне поставить галочку в Настройках приложений -> Дополнительные опции -> отладка по юсб, ну и следовательно подключить кабель к устройству. А потом в эклипсе можно просто нажимать run и приложение будет запускаться непосредственно на устройстве.